# No module named virtualenvwrapper

Tags: django, python-2.7, installation, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have Django 1.9.7 installed, and its works fine, but every time I open the terminal, I get this message.

```
If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

When I startproject in Django, it works fine. I wonder whether this will cause problems in the future, and how can I fix it?

I speculate that it is causing this problem because I used to use Python 2.7 with Django 1.9.7. I have recently upgrade by python to 2.4, but it seems that my packages for python 2.7 still exist in my computer. However, when I tried removing the python 2.7 packages with pip uninstall python == 2.7, I get this error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in   main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 336, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/f7/jrgwm7ms037f4v9lydh4cjcr0000gn/T/pip-dSXtam-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/Python-2.7.10-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I have read that it is not good to uninstall packages using pip because it does uninstall everything, but I am not sure how else to do it, and I am not sure how to fix the module issue either.